# Automatically refresh data when opening the report in Power BI Services

Tags: automation, refresh, powerbi

I wanted to know if it is possible to refresh the data of a report when we open this one, in order to always see updated data in the report. I explain myself, if I publish a report in a workspace (other users have access to this workspace), I want that every time they open a report, this one would be updated.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are importing data, I'm not sure if this is possible or not.

However, if you set up a [Direct Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-use-directquery), then your data is pulled as you interact with the report.